# Description of folder structure of Qt SDK

Tags: qt, installation, directory

Do you know any resource describing Qt SDK folder structure?

I'm wondering why some of dll files are in c:\qt\2009.03\bin and in c:\qt\2009.03\qt\bin at the same time? Having the same name they have different sizes (for example QtCore4.dll - 2 016 256 bytes in the first folder and 2 730 496 bytes in the second folder). What's the difference between dll files with the same names in both folders?

SDK default installation path is c:\qt\2009.03 and qt ends up being installed in c:\qt\2009.03\qt. Shouldn't qt be rather installed in let's say c:\qt-4.5.2 instead? Can I split SDK's qt from the rest of SDK and point SDK to the new location of qt?

Answer (score 3):

The *qt* subdirectory is the framework.  That's what you'd get if you just downloaded the framework.  The higher level *bin* directory contains the bits needed to actually run QtCreator.  QtCreator is apparently compiled with Visual Studio (on Windows), and I think the *qt* framework libs are compiled with MinGW.

You can recompile QtCreator and all the bits you need to remove the duplication...  and move stuff around...  but why bother?  You'll just have to do it all again in a few months with 4.5.3, 4.6.0, or whatever is on the way next.

*Deployment* is another matter.  That's something where I *would* care about directory structures, etc.  There's some documentation on what you basically need to do by TrollTech/Nokia [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/deployment.html).